# How to not feel weird when buying girl clothes as a teen boy

Tags: public-issues, gender, shopping

I'm a young high school student that really like dressing up as a girl in my house when my parents aren't here I usually use my mom’s clothes but I wanna get my own too. I really don't know how to go approach a cashier with girl’s tights!  I really want a white pair but I'm too afraid that people will look at me awkwardly.  Most other people that buy girl cloths are men so they can say for thier. Wife or daughter but as a grade 8 boy what should I say?? And the other question may just be other cloths my question is how to not feel awkward when buying a pair of tights/pantyhose

Answer (score 1):

If it makes you feel better, most people will probably think you're a loving boyfriend buying some clothes for his girlfriend :) And if someone asks who its for just reply with a non-answer like "None of your business whats going on with my life"

Comment: Even if this answer may work quite often it's actually quite rude, if the OP doesn't feel like it lying about a potential girlfriend may help a lot.